# React-native package return undefined

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I've installed [react-native-google-places](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places) as per the instructions, but when I try run the app I get this error:

[image]

Here are the steps I took:

1) `react-native init awesomeApp && cd awesomeApp`

2) `yarn add react-native-google-places`

3) `react-native link react-native-google-places`

4) In /ios folder I create the podfile with this content

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'awesomeApp' do
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
end
```

5) I create an API key with google (I'll share this one for now but will disable it later: `AIzaSyA5u8ez8uuyGvAa98XzH7rY1MCnHrED-rw`)

6) I update my AppDelegate.m file to look like this:

```
@import GooglePlaces;
@import GoogleMaps;

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  [GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyDEmY7AqrJbrr1oD4Pe82H_xAHt3C0xafM"];
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyDEmY7AqrJbrr1oD4Pe82H_xAHt3C0xafM"];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"awesomeApp"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
@end
```

7) I run `pod install` from /ios

8) Then `react-native run-ios` from root

9) I include `import RNGooglePlaces from 'react-native-google-places';` in index.ios.js

10) Then add `RNGooglePlaces.openAutocompleteModal();` inside the render function before the `return`

These steps for as far as I can tell should yield a modal with a google places autocomplete. Can someone please point out why it doesn't?

Comment: is the problem solved. ?

Comment: No. I abandoned the package and rolled my own

Comment: can you share the solution for reference?

Comment: I do not own the code so I cannot share it here unfortunately. I basically set up a Redux action to call the suggestions API every time the user changes their input